# Is there a way to insert in MySQL a trigger of corresponding rows for each ID?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to create an order which then inserts multiple rows into another table. Which will work like the following:

User selects one or more items from tableOfStuff then places an order which INSERTS a new order into tableOrders. When this insert is created I need to copy the ID created for that order into a TRIGGER which then creates multiple rows in tableOrderDetails. In this table I want a row created for each of the IDs from tableOfStuff and then the one new OrderID (that gets created for the order) repeated in each of these rows.

How would I achieve this in MySQL? Any tutorials or examples would be great or topic areas I should search the net for?

> TableOfStuff - PK: ToS_ID

> TableOrders - PK: ToO_ID

> TableOfStuffOrders - FK: ToS_ID && ToO_ID

ToO_ID would only be one ID but the ToS_ID would be one or more IDs.

Comment: You cannot pass parameters to a trigger, so not really suitable for this job. This is really a job for a transaction and you can write a simple sql script or a stored procedure to accomplish this

Comment: Thank you @Shadow I will dive deeper into stored procedures